# How to play sound in media stream with MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an audio record in file, and trying to play it with MediaPlayer:

```java
player = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, Uri.fromFile(record));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    player.setAudioAttributes(
            new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                    .build()
    );
} else {
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
player.setVolume(1f, 1f);
player.setLooping(false);
player.start();
```

But when I change volume with volume buttons when record is playing it will change volume in notification channel instead media channel. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more accurate? Of what I can see, your problem comes from your phone which does change right volume channel. It depends on your Android phone, some of them change all volume channels at the same time.

See following answer from Google [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/9082609?hl=en)

If you click on your settings wheel while changing volume and selected general volume, your app will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It needs to write:

```java
activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
```

From docs `Activity#setVolumeControlStream`:

> Suggests an audio stream whose volume should be changed by the hardware volume controls.